# How to create glob pattern to access all sub folder and its own folder?

Tags: gulp, glob

I got a main folder and under it, it has a sub folders generated dynamically with boilerplate of folders and files.

Folder structure: http://www.screencast.com/t/WLFrIeYfm60o

Below is my sample code for javascripts:

```
var gulp            = require('gulp'),
runTaskSeq      = require('gulp-sequence'),
uglifyjs        = require('gulp-uglify'),
uglifycss       = require('gulp-uglifycss'),
sourcemaps      = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
concatjs        = require('gulp-concat'),
concatcss       = require('gulp-concat-css'),
rename          = require('gulp-rename'),
autoprefixer    = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
del             = require('del'),
fs              = require('fs');

// log errors
function errorLog(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    this.emit('end');
}

// script task
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('mainfolder/**/public/js/**/*/*.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(concatjs('temp.js'))
            .pipe(uglifyjs())
            .on('error', errorLog)
            .pipe(rename('build.min.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('mainfolder/**/public/js'));
});
```

Comment: When you say how "to access" do you mean for gulp.src or gulp.dest?  Is your gulp.src() working?

Comment: @Mark, It's for both gulp.src and gulp.dest that didn't work..

Comment: @Mark, it is now fixed. I just transfer the package.json, gulpfile.js and also the node_modules inside the sub folder of the mainfolder. It is caused by folder permission. Thanks for  your time.